# How can I write on to a file without overwriting it in java?

Tags: java, java-io

```
 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("data.txt")); //Reading the file
 String data [] = readFile (input); //data is each line in the file
 String student [] = new String [10];
 for(int x = 0; x<data.length; x++)
  {                
   student = data[x].split(","); //each line is being split into 11 parts
  }
```

I need to write in this file without overwriting it. I ask 10 questions like, "What is your first name?", and "What is your last name?". I need the answers of these questions going into a student []. Like I said, I need the code to write into this file without overwriting it.

Comment: I see input in this code but no output. How are you planning on writing to a file without any output?

Comment: You can *append* (keyword) to a file without overwriting it.

Comment: I think "append" is the word you're looking for, and it requires opening the file in a particular mode and observing some restrictions about how you reference it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PrintWriter out = null;
try {

out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfilename", 

true)));
    out.println("the text");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace ();
} 
finally {
  if (out != null) {
     out.close ();
  }
}
```

The second parameter to the FileWriter constructor will tell it to append to the file (as opposed to clearing the file).

Comment: +1 Please use `try-with-resources` or `close()` in finally, never empty catch `do some log` or something like that :)

Comment: @nachokk You are absolutely correct and the SO code that I copied was merely pasted without alteration.  I amended the answer.

Comment: *"The SO code I copied"* ... you mean like, someone else's answer, from a question this should have been flagged as a dup of?